# git:HTTP request failed?

Tags: git, https, centos

when I use git clone in CentOS release 6.5 (Final) and the output is following:

Initialized empty Git repository in /home/tje/zigbee/.git/
error: Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl while accessing https://github.com/danw/zigbee/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed

I have seen the same problem here and I delete one libcurl.so.4 in one place(there is really two libcurl.so.4), however, it still didn't work, I have wasted hours and been waiting for help...

by the way I success to git clone projects when I use git address like this: git@github.com:danw/zigbee.git

Comment: Why did you tag it with erlang?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your git address

instead of

```
$ git clone git@github.com:danw/zigbee.git
```

try doing

```
$ git clone https://github.com/danw/zigbee.git
```